# Why on earth can I not import nashpy into my Python library?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import nashpy as nash
```

I'm attempting to import nashpy but I keep receiving the error message below despite already pip installing nashy:

---

```
File "G:\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\python-3.5.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'
>>>
```

---

Could you help me understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the line which is causing the error, you'll see this:

```
from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
```

This line comment states the dependency as numpy+mkl (numpy with Intel Math Kernel Library). This means that you've installed the numpy by pip, but the scipy was installed by precompiled archive, which expects numpy+mkl.

This problem can be easy solved by installation for numpy+mkl from whl file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).